# Could not load requested class : oracle:jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, maven

I'm doing an app with hibernate 5.4.7 and oracle 12c. I was working with mySQL, and app works fine, but, when I change for oracle, it throws an exception. I'm using maven and tomcat 9.

This is the persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1"> <persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE">
<description>Archivo de persistencia Hibernate JPA</description>
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle:jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="system" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456789" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" />   
</properties>
```

This is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.survey</groupId>
<artifactId>survey</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Survey</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncodign>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncodign>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13-beta-3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
        <version>8.0.17</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId> <artifactId>com.springsource.oracle.jdbc</artifactId> 
        <version>10.2.0.2</version> </dependency> -->


</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
        <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>main</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
                <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <finalName>survey</finalName>
</build>
```

In DAO classes, I'm connecting of that way:

```
EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

/**
 * Crea una nueva interacción en la base de datos.
 * @param dtoInteraction. Objeto con información de la interacción.
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void saveInteraction(DTOInteraction dtoInteraction) throws Exception {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(dtoInteraction);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    JPAUtil.shutdown();
}
```

This is a JPAUtil Class:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
public class JPAUtil {
private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "PERSISTENCE";
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    factory=null;
    if (factory==null) {
        factory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    }
    return factory;             
}

public static void shutdown() {
    if (factory!=null) {
        factory.close();
    }       
}
}
```

This is the exceptions:

> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [oracle:jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oracle:jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I'm new with oracle and hibernate, any idea about the problem?

Comment: `oracle:jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is not a valid class name. Replace the `:` by a `.`. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem... Now it works